# Limit focus to elements within modal dialog

Tags: javascript, html

I created a library which I use to show different dialogs to users with JavaScript. This library generate code similar to the following:

```
<div id="dialog-overlay">
    <!-- focus must be allowed to elements within this DIV only -->
    <div class="dialog">
        <input ... />
        ...
        <button type="button">OK</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I have is that when I use `TAB` key to switch between elements, it also set focus to elements outside of my modal dialog.

What is the best way to solve this problem and limit focus to elements within my modal dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Limit focus only to your modal will be a problem, what you can do is set `focus` on the first element of your dialog, as is the expected behaviour, then on your last element you can add a event listener on `keyup`/`keydown`which should make a focus again on the first element.
Otherwise will be very messy to disable the `focus`/`tabindex`on the elements on your background

**Update**

Check the tab key pressed with something like this:

```
function tabPressHandler(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {
      $('.modelFirstElement').focus();
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
```